# PHP SVG Check with fallback, possible?

Tags: php, svg, fallback

is it possible to check (with PHP) if the browser supports SVG?

like ...

```
if( BROWSER support SVG )
{
   $iT = 'svg';              // Icon type
}
else
{
   $iT = 'png';              // Icon type
}
```

in HTML code ...

```
<img src="icons/home.<?=$iT?>" class="icon" />
```

**EDIT:**
How about to check the browser and the version? Good idea?

```
$data['browser'] = strtolower($data['browser']);

if     ($data['browser'] == 'firefox' && (int)$data['browser']['version'] >= 10)
       $iT = 'svg';

elseif ($data['browser'] == 'safari'  && (int)$data['browser']['version'] >= 5)
       $iT = 'svg';

 .... and so on
```

PS: Did anybody know a nice SVG-Browser-Support-List?

Comment: Hardcoded browser sniffing is a very bad idea, test for the feature instead. You could use e.g Modernizr (http://modernizr.com) for this, and let the actual testing-for-svg-support happen in the client where it belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do the check using JavaScript and Raphael, and then send that back to the server.

Comment: That means -> no chance for me to check this with php?

Comment: You could look at the user agent string, and look into a capability database, but that's not a great way to do it. Other than that, I am not sure there _is_ a way to do this server side, since it is the browser you're testing, not the server. As I say, if you want this information _on_ the server, just send the information back (in an AJAX call).

Comment: Imho is an ajax call to the server not a good idea (too huge workaround).

Comment: It's not a workaround at all. You need to ask the browser for its support capability, since the browser on the user's computer is the definitive source for whether it can render an SVG file. A capability database is much more of a workaround, since (a) a browser that supports SVG may have had this feature turned off, and (b) the list requires constant updating as new browsers are released.